# how to update kml file in google map api v3?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

My KML file had been uploaded into my Google Map account. But how can I update it without upload again. For example, I want to allow user can change one polygon's color in website. Can user use my account to update my KML file and show it dynamic?

Firstly, I try to use Google Maps Data API and log in my account, but it not work.

```
    <form  method="post" action="https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin"> 
<input type="hidden" name="accountType" value="GOOGLE" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="Email" value="**@gmail.com" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="Passwd" value="***" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="service" value="local" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="source" value="mycompany-myapp-1" /> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

Then I get auth="DQ****", and use this auth to do next step:

```
   <form method="get" action="http://maps.google.com/maps/feeds/maps/default/full"> 
<input type="hidden" name="Authorization" value="GoogleLogin" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="auth" value="DQ***"/> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
```

Will get error......

In fact, I just want to make a webpage that allow users to make their own shade maps. I have a KML file of combining many polygons. And these polygon have different style. How can users update polygons' style?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

Other users can't change your Google Map account data.

One option would be to import that kml into a FusionTable, then use dynamic styling to change its color.  If you want them to be able to change the color and save that change, you could write code to change styling information in the FusionTable, but everyone would see the change, not clear if that is what you want or not.

Comment: Thanks. I have added some details, and I have not used FusionTable API. But everyone can see the change is not allowed. I will learn FusionTable first, and Thank you all the same.